# How to avoid special chars change on file copy

Tags: laravel, csv, ftp

A customer put once a day a csv file to an ftp server.

With a laravel application, I copy the file to my server.

```
        $files = Storage::disk('xxxxMasterData')->allFiles();

        foreach ($files as $file) {

            $fileToCopy = Storage::disk('xxxxMasterData')->get($file);

            Storage::disk('localXxxxlMasterData')->put($file, $fileToCopy);

            if(env('APP_ENV') === 'production') {
                Storage::disk('xxxxMasterData')->delete($file);
            }
        }
```

The content of the file on the ftp server ist ok. The special chars are ok:

```
438186|DM1210DWS|D1=4 L1=14 D2=4 L2=50 Z=2|DWS|Schaftfräser|Fraise en bout|
```

When I open the copied file, the word `Schaftfräser` has changed to `Schaftfr�ser`!

It looks like this:

```
438186|DM1210DWS|D1=4 L1=14 D2=4 L2=50 Z=2|DWS|Schaftfr�ser|Fraise en bout|
```

I tried to read only the content from the ftp server, but it return also the `Schaftfr�ser`!

Is there a setting to do on laravel or on the ftp server to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the encoding:

```
$fileToCopyEncoded = mb_convert_encoding($fileToCopy, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
```